# Using jQuery Fancybox or Lightbox to display a contact form

Tags: jquery, lightbox, fancybox

I would like to use jQuery Fancybox or Lightbox to load a contact form from a standard link in a web page. I have reviewed the documents at http://fancybox.net/example but the closest option is the iFrame one and it doesn't work with a standard page link.

My heart is not set on using Fancybox so if there is a better way to have the lightbox effect with a contact form I would appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction.

thanks.

Comment: I am using Fancybox for pop-up forms and it's working great.  Why weren't you able to use a standard page link?

Comment: There is an example here:
http://fancybox.net/blog Scroll down to:
#5 Display login form works great!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you'll probably want to look into [jquery-ui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). it's highly customizable and can be made to work exactly like lightbox/fancybox and supports everything you would need for a contact form from a regular link.

there is even an [example with a form](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form).

Comment: Hey there. I finally had a chance to look at this and it will work perfectly. Thanks for passing it along.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at: [Greybox](http://orangoo.com/labs/GreyBox/)

It's an awesome version of lightbox that supports forms, external web pages as well as the traditional images and slideshows.  It works perfectly from a link on a webpage.

You will find many information on how to use Greybox and also some great examples.
Cheers
Kara

Comment: Hi, how can I style the formbox, wanted to continue using blueprint css?  Also, noticed that it uses iFrames....a way to not use it?

Answer (score 1):

Greybox cannot handle forms inside it on its own. It requires a forms plugin. No iframes or external html files needed. Don't forget to download the greybox.css file too as the page misses that bit out.

Kiss Jquery UI goodbye and a lightbox hello.
[You can get it here.](http://corky.net/dotan/programming/jquery.dialog/dialog-demo.html)